# Using \only on a block - beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is there a way to make the command `\only` work on a block in `beamer`?

Or is there another way to make a block appear and then disappear?

Here is a part of my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Creation des outils principaux}
  % - Le titre doit résumer le transparent dans un langage compréhensible
  %   par tous ceux qui ne suivront rien de ce qu'il y a sur ce transparent.
  \begin{itemize}
        \item Recuperation des donnees entrées dans le terminal
            \only<2>{
                \begin{exampleblock}{Opt Parse}
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=0]
import optparse
def parser():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(        description = "Dessinateur de fonctions")
    parser.add_option('-o', type=str, action = "store",
                        default="out.ppm", dest="filename",
                        help='filename. Default : out.ppm')
    return parser.parse_args()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    (opts, args) = parser()
\end{lstlisting}
                \end{exampleblock}
            }
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had the same problem when using a tikZ \matrix command. All `block`s afterwards need not start with `\only` but with `\begin{block}{title}<5->`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see your problem. I built this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title of this frame}
% first block appears at first
\only<1>{
    \begin{block}{First block}
    Hello
    \end{block}
}
% first block disappears and the second appears
\only<2>{
    \begin{block}{Second block}
    Hello again
    \end{block}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

getting these two frames:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the frame number is always the same and the second block appears after the first one, that is not more visible.

> **Edit**

After you posted your MWE I got your problem. Maybe my solution will not completely satisfy you, but it works.

First: the option `fragile` is needed anyway. Secondly, since I noticed that the code occupies more or less the whole frame (even setting the font size smaller), I decided in my solution to put it outside the `itemize` environment.

This is the new MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle={\footnotesize}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Creation des outils principaux}
  % - Le titre doit résumer le transparent dans un langage compréhensible
  %   par tous ceux qui ne suivront rien de ce qu'il y a sur ce transparent.
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Recuperation des donnees entrées dans le terminal
\end{itemize}
\begin{exampleblock}{Opt Parse}<2>
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=0]
import optparse
def parser():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(        description = "Dessinateur de fonctions")
    parser.add_option('-o', type=str, action = "store",
                        default="out.ppm", dest="filename",
                        help='filename. Default : out.ppm')
    return parser.parse_args()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    (opts, args) = parser()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is shown in the following two frames:

[image]

[image]

Notice that the key point is having inserted `<1->` to the `item` and `<2>` for the `exampleblock`. In this way the sentence of the `item` is still visible when the `exampleblock` appears.

Comment: When I do yours it's working but mine keep being stuck
 Maybe it's because the block are in a itemize?

Comment: @kasmanit: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem!

Comment: In fact it seems that it's the listing with the code that cause trhe problem, when I remove it it's working

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to use the frame option `fragile` when you inserted the code by means of `listings`.

Comment: When I add the `fragile` It gave me utf8x error (i gonna fix this later, it's not the main problem), beacause it says that there is missing `}` but I am sure tht everything is fine

Comment: Now I see your problem and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, otherwise if I put the code in a file and include with `\lstinputlisting` it's working

Comment: Thaks it fully satisfy me

Comment: Just to add for future readers: if your code has curly braces inside, and you want to wrap it in  an \only block, you can use \begin{onlyenv} and \end{onlyenv} to avoid the error you got.

Answer (score 6):

A variant of Claudio's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52667/111814) can be obtained by modifying the *action specifications* of the `block` environment, as explained in the [Beamer User Guide for version 3.50](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) in Section 9.6.3.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title of this frame}
% first block appears at first
\begin{block}<only@1>{First block} % <-- note the "only@" here...
    Hello
\end{block}
% first block disappears and the second appears
\begin{block}<only@2>{Second block} % <-- and here
    Hello again
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for